# Error adding controller with scaffolding "There was an error running..." in VS2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

While adding controller am getting "There was  an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is  outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647].
Parameter name: value'"
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Try By rebuilding the Project , if it still not works try just giving ViewName, Template, Model class and leave 'data context class' as empty.
>   It worked for me.

Comment: Actually m not able to add empty view or empty controller.